# Is tension always present?

Tags: chord-theory

I tension always present in a music? Sometimes I hear a simple acoustic song that has only two or three chords. What's more these chords are played in sequence: I -> ii -> I -> ii  Is there any tension at all? It seems to be raising and being resolved just a second later.

Is there any tension at all? Is it required?

Comment: It's most likely that either one of those 2 chords is the tonic, so the other will (most likely) create some tension. There are exceptions though, like for major I - VI (both function as rests).

Comment: The song I am talking about is Everybody Hurts by R.E.M. and is written in D major scale I suppose. In an acoustic version it goes like this: I -> IV -> I - IV and then goes to ii -> V -> ii -> V. I ends with I so I can see that there is a tension resolved, yeah, but what about the parts where we play two chords again and again? Do they create tension? What is their function?

Comment: Yes, IV grade functions as subdominant so it creates a small amount of tension, which is resolved when it goes back to I (tonic).

Comment: Thanks! I am just a little bit confused about the tension being built and resolved all the time during the verse instead of building it and resolving at the end of the section (verse). It just happens again and again.

Comment: I consider your example (I -> ii -> I -> ii) as setting up tension by moving from a chord with tonic function to one with subdominant function. For comparison, compare that to I -> III -> I -> III, where both the I and the III both have tonic function and so far less tension and release, although there is still some tension and release because the I chord is the tonic itself and the III chord is less so. So, imho, tension and release is a relative phenomena and is more likely to be imperceptible than not there at all.

Answer (score 3):

'It seems to be raising and being resolved...' The resolution comes after what? The tension! Maybe not a huge amount, but you noticed it yourself!

Most pieces of music will be 'in a key'. Resolution is often noticed at the points where the music settles on that key chord, or note/s that constitute it. That's when it could be a finish for that section. So, yes, pretty well all music will have that tension-resolution in some form or another, at some points along the way. For example, if a piece in C had several harmonies which culminated in, say, Dm> G> F...the listener would be expecting something to follow. If it just stopped there, it would be unresolved. If the next chord is G, then it's still unresolved, so there's still tension. It needs that C to appear to 'come back home', and then there's resolution.

Is it required? A big question. It depends on the mood the writer wants to provide. In a dreamy, sleep inducing piece, it would most likely sound out of place somewhat. In a stirring, or awe-inspiring piece, without tension, there's not going to be much stir or awe!

Comment: Yeah. I can see your point, but the song is kinda chilly and during the verse when the singer slowly goes with his lyrics, there is I -> IV -> I -> IV progression repeated again and again. So resolving does not come at the end of the verse but happens again and again during the verse. That's what confuses me a bit heh, because I thought it is supposed to happen at the end of the section.

Comment: All it's doing is teasing. You'd like something to happen sooner, but it's just not going to. That's the nature of the beast. In a way, it's producing its own tension, in a slightly different way. Little like the 1st 4 bars of a 12 bar blues - you get to bar 4, and you're begging for a change - and it comes!

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Yeah teasing is a good word for this hah! Thanks you a lot Tim!!

Comment: Good question! Songs with one chord can genwerate tension by changing the mood of the sung melody (eg straightforward major key to a more soulful deluvery) or concentrating on a 7th note then back to major 3rd. etc.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "concentrating on a 7th note then back to major 3rd"?

Answer (score 0):

Tension takes on many forms: In tonal music (most classical music and pop/rock) tension is created from moving away from the tonic and returning to it (like in your example), and as our ears is so used to this kind of music, we automatically attributes this kind of tension to most of what we hear - tonal or not. But many modern composers has tried to create other kind of tensions unrelated to the tonal music - e.g. Arnold Schoenberg.

Is tension required at all. Thats a really good question. It certainly plays a role in most music we know.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the tension by labelling a chord as I.   If you consider one chord to be the tonic, there's tension when away from it, resolution when returning to it.

I agree, current pop/rock is not all about dominant-tonic relationships in the way Common Practice music was.   Non-functional meandering returned to mainstream music over 100 years ago.   Lots of choices now!